# Is it possible to use JavaScript to break the HTML of a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been asked at work whether it is possible to write, on purpose or by accident, JavaScript that will remove specific characters from a HTML document and thus break the HTML. An example would be adding some JavaScript that removes the < symbol in the page. I've tried searching online and I know JavaScript can replace strings, but my knowledge of the language is negligible.

I've been asked to look into it as a way of hopefully addressing why a site I work on needs to have controls over who can add bespoke functionality to the page. I'm hoping it's not possible but would be grateful for the peace of mind!

Comment: I think that if you write yourelement.innerHTML('<div<<>'); will break html °°

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and in fact you can do things far more insidious with javascript as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: XSS is not about breaking HTML.

Comment: @Tadeck Yes, but an assumption was made about why management might ask a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

yes, thats possible. the easiest example is

```
var body = document.getElemetsByTagName('body')[0];
body.innerHTML = 'destroyed';
```

wich will remove the whole page and just write "destroyed" instead. to get back to your example: in the same way it's possible to replace `<`:

```
var body = document.getElemetsByTagName('body')[0];
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace('<','some other character');
```

such "extreme" cases are very unlikely to happen by accident, but it's absolutely possible (particularly for inexperienced javascript-developers) to break things on a site that usually shouldn't be affected by javascript.

note that this will only mess op the displayed page in the clients browser and doesn't change your html-file on the server in any way. just find and remove/fix the "bad" lines of code and everything is fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Any client/browser can manipulate how the page is viewed at any time, for instance in chrome hit F12 and then you can write whatever you want in the html and you will see the changes immediately. But that's not to worry about...

The scary part is when JavaScript on the site communicates with the back-end server and supplies it with some input parameters that are not being sanitized on the server side before it is processed in some way. SQL Injection can also happen this way if the back-end utilizes a database which they almost always do, and so on...

A webpage can be manipulated in two ways, either its **none-persistent** or its **persistent.**

**[none-persistent]:** this way you can manipulate your access to a webpage but, this won't affect other users in it self, but you can do harm once your in.

**[persistent]:** this way the server side code will permanently be affected by the injected code, and most likely affect other users.

Key thing here is to always sanitize the input a back-end server used before it processes anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely write some javascript function to modify the contents of a file. If that file is your HTML page, then sure.

If you want to prevent this from happening, you can just set the permissions of that HTML file to be read-only, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could:

1. Overwrite the page,
2. Mess with the innerHTML of the body tag (almost the same),
3. Insert illegal elements.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. In the least, you could use it to write CSS that sets any element, class, ID... even the body to display:none;